# Max Date or Aggregate or TextJoin with Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Excel 2016, but not sure if it's office 365 with 15,000 records

I'm trying to find a way to show the last date/instance some construction work was been done to a suite.

The data set has unit numbers associated with construction work and the date the work was performed. I'm using Index Match to find the unit and give me the date, but it only finds the first instance of the unit, rather than the last instance.  Each unit may have had a dozen jobs performed, so I'm looking for the last instance.
I've tried using -1 in the MATCH function, but that didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution?  This is what I have so far.

```
(INDEX('Raw Data'!$U$2:$U$15000,MATCH($L3,'Raw Data'!$AX$2:$AX$15000,0))
```

Comment: Can you sort the data by date?

Comment: which column is the date and which is the suite number?

Comment: The suite number is under AX column and the dates are under U column.

Comment: I made sure Excel was reading the date format.  I used Text to column and ensured it was formatted as a date.  It's all nicely right-aligned and yes, I can sort the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INDEX('Raw Data'!$U$2:$U$15000,LARGE(IF('Raw Data'!$AX$2:$AX$15000=$L3,ROW('Raw Data'!$AX$2:$AX$15000) - ROW('Raw Data'!$AX$2) + 1,0),1))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried this, but it continued to give me the first instance, instead of the last.   It seems to follow the same thinking as the solution proposed by Scott below.  Thanks again for your input, you and Scott have helpe me and others in this forum learn.  thx Martin

Comment: Possibly if you have older version of Excel 365, you have to enter this as Array formula, by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter. At any rate, it would be nice if you accepted Scott's answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the max date:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,'Raw Data'!$U$2:$U$15000/(L3='Raw Data'!$AX$2:$AX$15000),1)
```

Comment: It WORKS!!  without Index or Match...I never saw that one coming.  Scott you're awesome!!  If I understand this formula correctly, the 14 represents LARGE and the 7 represents 'Ignore hidden rows and errors', but I'm not clear why you divided.  Also, the formua gives a #NUM result for units that have not had work.  Iferror( ," ") doesn't seem to work.